# Open source java library to read ECG data?

Tags: java, android, open-source

Can Someone suggest me a good open source java library to read ECG data in MFER / HL7 / Other formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options for a java library that parses HL7. For example, you could use the HAPI library, available on sourceforge at http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/. There is also a .NET version of that library at http://nhapi.sourceforge.net/home.php, for those that prefer that platform. Another Java-based option is HL7Comm at http://nule.org/wp/?page_id=63.

More options can be found on the Wikipedia page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7#Open_source_tools, and at http://www.hl7.org.au/HL7-Tools.htm.

For ECG processing in general, see the OpenECG portal at http://www.openecg.net/.

Answer (score 1):

One of the standard ECG software analysis libraries is WFDB and PhysioNet:
http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wag/wag.htm

Two American National Standards, ANSI/AAMI EC38:1998 (Ambulatory Electrocardiographs) and ANSI/AAMI EC57:1998 (Testing and Reporting Performance Results of Cardiac Rhythm and ST Segment Measurement Algorithms) require the use of several of the WFDB applications for evaluation of certain devices and algorithms.

There are wrappers written, so you can use Java to access the code:
http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-swig.shtml